# How to skip forms authentication to some controller actions in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web

in my asp.net mvc web application, i have forms authentication specified in web.config file. like this below

```xml
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

now i am creating a user activation page which does not requires any authentication. user activation action method is present in Account Controller. when user type www.myweb.com/account/useractivation i want to open page without any authentication. can anyone help me in this regard. i did spent some time in research but no luck

Answer (score 2):

Decorate the controller or action method which needs to bypass authentication with the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
```

Have a look at this article - [Securing your ASP.NET MVC 4 App and the new AllowAnonymous Attribute](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute/)